# Importing assets from an NPM Package

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

Say I want to include font-awesome in my webapp. So I define my build.sbt as follows:

```scala
val commonSettings = Seq(
    name := "repro",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
        baseDirectory.value / ".." / "shared" / "src" / "main" / "scala"
)
val client = project.in(file("client"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(
        npmDependencies in Compile ++= Seq(
            "font-awesome" -> "4.7.0",
        ),

    mainClass in Compile := Some("app.App"),

    scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true,

    webpackBundlingMode := BundlingMode.LibraryOnly(),
)
.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
.enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

val server = project.in(file("server"))
.settings(commonSettings: _*)
.settings(
    npmAssets ++= NpmAssets.ofProject(client) { nodeModules =>
        (nodeModules / "font-awesome").allPaths
    }.value
)
.enablePlugins(WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin)
```

Can I configure this project so that my "package" command will then include the css in my target/webapp folder? Or is there another command I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your configuration, you have to add the following settings to the `server` project:

```scala
.settings(
    scalaJSProjects := Seq(client),
    pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline),
    managedClasspath in Runtime += (packageBin in Assets).value,
    WebKeys.packagePrefix in Assets := "public/"
)
```

The first line introduces a dependency between the `server` project and the assets produced by the `client` project. The `scalaJSProjects` settings is introduced by the [sbt-web-scalajs](https://github.com/vmunier/sbt-web-scalajs) plugin.

The second line integrates the assets produced by the `client` project into the Web assets managed by [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web).

The third line tells sbt to include the assets produced by the sbt-web plugin to the classpath of the server.

The last line is optional, it simply puts the produced assets into the `public/` resource directory, so that they are not mixed with other classpath resources which are not meant to be exposed to the outside world.

With this configuration, you can build the production assets with the following command:

```
> server/web-assets:package
```

Or, from a build file, by using the `packageBin in Assets` task.

This will produce a `target/scala-2.12/repro_2.12-1.0-web-assets.jar` file containing the JavaScript bundle produced by Webpack on your `client` project, as well as the `font-awesome/` directory.